# Can I connect only two wires to GFCI receptacle?

Tags: gfci

My distribution panel's neutral bar is grounded. So I have only two wires coming out of the panel to the GFCI receptacle. The inspector tested the receptacle and said it's not GFCI.

I wonder if it's because I left the GFCI's ground entrance empty? If that's the reason, can I just connect it to the neutral, which is grounded already?

And, does the code require GFCI has to connect with 3 wires? 2 Wire is not OK?

Thanks!!!
-Henry

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly to code to replace a two-prong outlet (without an available ground) with a GFCI.

Never, ever, make a bootleg ground by connect the neutral to the ground pin. It may seem to work, bug under some extreme circumstances, you could end up with lethal voltages on the ground pin.

Comment: if you do place a GFCI without a ground connection then add a "no equipment ground" sticker to the outlet.